# Azure Hybrid connection manager stuck on "Saving please wait"

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-hybrid-connections

While connecting to Azure Hybrid connection manager I received following problem.

Once I authenticate I can see the connection and  I click on the connection and save the connection.

However the Connection manager keeps stuck on the "Saving... Please Wait".

[image]

Rebooting the VM does not solve this issue.
The Msservices provide following result --> "Running"

[image]

A "Test-NetConnection" to the service bus endpoint on port 443 succeeded.
Even reinstalling the HC manager did not solve the issue, Anyone who had the same issue can help me out here ?

Answer (score 3):

The only time I have seen this issue occur before was because the customer needed to use a global admin account to install and configure the HCM. Can you please try using a global admin account and report back the outcome? We look forward to your reply.

Comment: Hi, yes indeed the account settings did matter.
The user that tried to connect the HCM did not have enough rights. (either on the VM or on Azure). He could log in and select the web app. But when we tried using another user account the connection was established. Thanks for your input.

Comment: We also had the same effect when cloud-side permissions where missing. So maybe also check the permissions of the acting user on the relay namespace. AFAIK the "Azure Relay Owner" role fulfills the permission requirements.